# "Get XML Data" step of pentaho is not able to read same xml file sometimes

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using pentaho kettle tool for ETL job. In the job, one of the step(Get XML Data) is not able to read/parse xml file sometime. Sometime same XML file didn't throw any exception and sometime it threw. The list of errors are as given below -

- 1) Error on line 1 of document
  file:///D:/softwares/pdi-ce-6.0.1.0-386/data-integration/UTF-8 : The
  element type "Confidence" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
  "".
- 2) org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line -1 of document  :
  Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.

However, i don't find any issue in xml file. Could anyone help on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the root cause but got the solution. The xml file which was being parsed by the step, was inside the zip file. Before parsing the xml file, a java step was unzipping the zip file. Instead of unzipping the zip file, i directly parsed the xml file inside the zip. That resolves the issue and no any error is reported again.